# Crystal Report: ERROR : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, driver

I am getting the following error when I try to run a report in Crystal report.
Could you suggest a way to get rid of this error:
ERROR : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: Is the `ODBC` connection exists in your target system that is present in crystal report?

Comment: yes i have checked odbcad*.exe also.But still it shows the same error.

Comment: May be you need just restart the crystal and system...

Comment: doesnot serve the purpose.i tried that too!!

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you it can't find the DSN you specified.  On Windows you can create User data sources and System data sources.  If the DSN you created to use with Crystal was a User DSN and your app runs under another user you won't find the DSN.  If this is the case, try creating a System DSN and see if it fixes the problem.